# Understanding renice

Tags: linux, scheduler

I'm trying to give an CPU-bound application the lowest scheduling priority with `renice 19` (Linux 3.11). However, it doesn't seem to work as expected or I have an understanding problem.

Let me describe two ways how I've tried it. I expected that in both ways I'd get the same results, but I don't. Consider the application `loop` to be a busy loop: `int main() { for(;;) ; return 0; }`.

#### Experiment 1

- opened a terminal
- ran `./loop &` as many times as CPUs (eg, I have 4 CPUs).
- ran a further instance of `loop` and reniced it to 19

Result was as expected. The non-reniced `loop` instances have almost 100% CPU each, and the reniced instance has about 1%.

#### Experiment 2

- opened two terminals
- Terminal 1: ran `./loop &` as many times as CPUs.
- Terminal 2: ran a further instance of `loop` and renice it to 19

Result was not as expected. The `loop` instance started in Terminal 2 had 100% (although with niceness 19), whereas the `loop` instances in Terminal 1 shared the rest of the resources.

#### Question

Why does not experiment 2 behave as experiment 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have autogroups enabled.

In that case, in experiment 2 at the top level you have 2 control groups (one per session) competing for CPU, and inside each control group processes compete for CPU.

You can see the current control group and its niceness with:

```
cat /proc/$$/autogroup
```

And you can set the niceness with:

```
echo 19 > /proc/$$/autogroup
```